# Android Jelly Bean 4.1.2: People app doesn't display birthday event

Tags: android, contacts, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-syncadapter

I'm writing an android contacts sync adapter. I successfully managed to retrieve contacts data from an external service provider and to insert their data in the android contact provider. The data i'm inserting is: profile picture, first name, middle name, last name, websites ,birthdays and stream items.

All data i'm inserting is correctly displayed by the standard android People app, except birthday events.

Here's the code i use to insert birthday events:

```
op = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, existingRawId)
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(Event.START_DATE, bDay)
    .withValue(Event.TYPE, Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY);
```

where `bDay` is a String with the following format: yyyy-MM-dd

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong or why birthday events are not displayed in the People app?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, looking from the AOSP source code, it appears that the Contacts app only handles Event data kinds for Google and Exchange account types. So, apparently, it is impossible to make the app show birthday events for any custom account type.